# Tree structured sidebar in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia

I have completed my mediawiki sidebar as follows.

```
*product1
**Welcome
**Introduction
**User Guide

*product2
**Welcome
**Introduction
**User Guide
```

i have completed this using vector extension,but my requirement is to have a 3 model hierarchy like this

```
*Product1
**Welcome
    ***Welcome1
    ***Welcome2
    ***Welcome3
 **Introduction
    ***Introduction1
    ***Introduction2
    ***Introduction3
 **User guide
    ***User guide1
    ***User guide2
    ***User guide3
```

the product will have 3 sub links like  Welcome,introduction,UserGuide ,
Welcome will have Welcome1,WElcome2,welcome ,i would like to bring this as the third hierarchy in the sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Add to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgHooks['SkinBuildSidebar'][] = "fnSidebarMultiLevel";
function fnSidebarMultiLevel(Skin $skin, &$bar) {

  global $wgOut;

  $sPanel = "* Product1
** Welcome
*** Welcome1
*** Welcome2
*** Welcome3";

  $bar = array("Nav" => $wgOut->parse($sPanel)) + $bar;

}
```

will work in version 1.14 and above.

Comment: Thank you for the hack, but it has some problems: 1. if concatenate in reverse order: `$bar + array("Nav" => $wgOut->parse($sPanel))` a "Nav" title appears; 2. The text is visible to not authenticated users too; 3. Text styling is awful.

Comment: @Paul 1. and what's wrong? 2. as expected 3. not related to question.

Comment: `and what's wrong?`: 1. the behavior in original order and in reverse order differs. No idea how to show the "Nav" title in first case and hide it in second case; 2. if I want to show some other title than "Nav", in Cyrillics, I have no idea how to do this. 3. I would like not only show the text but make it understandable, good-looking and functional (i.e. if there is a visually foldable/unfoldable level, folding/unfolding should really work). It seems that I have to use some plug-in.

Comment: @Paul 1. you can hide it with css or js 2. you need to save `LocalSettings.php` in UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a third level out of the box. For this you will need either to use a custom skin, or create an extension.

If you know some PHP you can try and use the [SkinBuildSidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinBuildSidebar) hook to render the sidebar as you want it.

Comment: I am also messing with the same problem,I was thinking ,can I have the tree structure with three levels inside the page? I dont want table of contents ,is there any extension to do this ?